# Delete a dictionary key and value through .onDelete(perform: delete)

Tags: swift, dictionary, swiftui

The list below is populated with a Dictionary

```
@State private var currencyList: [String:String] = [:]
```

The delete function is as follows, however IndexSet is not applicable for a dictionary.

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet){
        print(" currency list  before \(currencyList)")
        currencyList.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        print(" currency list after \(currencyList)")
    }
```

```
List{
            ForEach(currencyList.sorted(by: >), id: \.key){ key, value in
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "centsign.circle")
                    Text(value)
                    
                    Text(key)
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ``` currencyList.sorted(by: >).remove(atOffsets: offsets) ``` cannot use mutating member on immutable value. Deleting the entry of the list where the delete was swiped on is all that's needed, I tried to find the index by key and removeValue but that didn't work

Comment: Yes of course, the result is immutable. My bad. I still think you should have an array property instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet){
    print(" currency list  before \(currencyList)")
    if let ndx = offsets.first {
        let item = currencyList.sorted(by: >)[ndx]
        currencyList.removeValue(forKey: item.key)
        print(" currency list after \(currencyList)")
    }
}
```

Comment: if this answered your question, could you mark it as correct please (the tick mark to turn green).